# Extract a 2D array of dictionary values

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, multidimensional-array, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary `dic` with a single key `'Band_1'` and a 2D array of values. I want to simply extract these values from the dictionary as a 2D array, but I must keep the same index/ structure. The dictionary looks like:

```
{'Band_1': array([[ 72284.15387234,  71911.10445312,  76238.47771614, ...,
         43633.95847573,  45275.37592033,  45499.20557187],
       [ 70493.51666005,  70120.46724083,  72358.76375619, ...,
         40127.293935  ,  39381.19509655,  38709.70614194],
       [ 76238.47771614,  76238.47771614,  76238.47771614, ...,
         42738.63986959,  42440.20033421,  43037.07940497],
       ...,
       [ 45275.37592033,  45872.25499109,  45275.37592033, ...,
         25727.58635285,  24309.99855979,  24384.60844364],
       [ 47812.11197107,  50871.11720873,  49005.8701126 , ...,
         30875.66833818,  31845.59682817,  31770.98694433],
       [ 44007.00789496,  45499.20557187,  45349.98580418, ...,
         26622.904959  ,  28935.8113582 ,  31547.15729279]])}
```

Thus far I have tried:

```
for key, values in dic.iteritems():
        for x in values[0]:
            array.append(x)
            for y in values[1]:
                array.append(y)
```

and

```
for keys, values in dic.items():
        array = [[y for y in values[1]] x for x in values[0]]
```

I need an efficient way of doing this as the array will be quite large?

Comment: Please provide desired output. "keep the same index/ structure" is not quite clear

Comment: wouldn't ['Band_1'][0] be just the thing you want? A bit confusing, what is the desired result?

Comment: I also do not understand what your output has to look like. Despite that `dic['Band_1']` returns the array.

Comment: @AlekseiMaide The desired result is a 2D array, not a 2D array within a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "dic" variable contains the array, when you access it be key, it gets returned...

```
array = dic['Band_1']
```

Gives you the inner array...

Just as any other item in dictionary:

```
dict = {'key': 'value'}
dict['key'] #returns 'value'
```